# grep error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to compare two files to see if all strings (in this case lines are fine though they are not ordered) from `file1` are present somewhere in `file 2`.

I did a bit of research and it seems the command `grep -v -f file1 file2` should be able to do this however I get the error repetition-operator operand invalid when I try this in command line.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: you should show the content of `file1`, which is the one containing the regexps

Comment: The content in file1 is 3 columns of real numbers.

Comment: With plus signs?

Comment: Yes there are plus signs when there are exponents ie 1.132E+003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that one or more lines in *file1* do not respect regular expression syntax. If you are looking for strings as-is, and not for regular expressions, you should use the option `-F` (fixed strings).

However, the real problem is that you cannot use `grep` for your purpose, because shorter lines may match longer lines erroneously. For example, if *file1* contains an empty line then that line will match *all* lines in *file2*.

A better approach is to sort the files and use `diff`:

```
TmpFile1=$(mktemp)
TmpFile2=$(mktemp)
sort $File1 >$TmpFile1
sort $File2 >$TmpFile2
# Display the lines in $File1 which do not appear in $File2
diff $TmpFile1 $TmpFile2 | grep '^>' | cut -c 3-
# Delete the temporary files
rm $TmpFile1 $TmpFile2
```

Comment: “shorter lines may match longer lines erroneously” That's easily solved with `grep -x`.